# How to test angular component which has setTimeout inside ngOnInt using jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing unit test in jamsine and I am using nvd3 to display chart.

**chart.component.ts**

```
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {

    chartConfigs = [];
    @Input chartDetails;

    ngOnInit() {
        if(chartDetails.data) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.chartConfigs.push('1');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**chart.component.spec.ts**

```
it('shall render the chart', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.chartComponent.data = [
        { x: 0, y: 3.160340011 },
        { x: 1, y: 5.16379641 },
        { x: 2, y: 1.16379641 },
        { x: 3, y: -1.16379641 },
        { x: 4, y: 0.379641 },
        { x: 5, y: 0 },
        { x: 6, y: -15.16379641 },
        { x: 7, y: -111.16379641 }
    ]];
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.chartComponent.chartConfigs.length).toBe(0);
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const chartElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('nvd3');
    expect(chartElement.hasChildNodes()).toBeTruthy(); //  error: Cannot read property 'hasChildNodes' of null
    expect(component.chartComponent.chartConfigs.length).toBe(1); // error: length is 0
}));
```

**chart.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="chartConfigs.length" >
    <nvd3 [chartConfig]="chartConfigs[0]" [data]="[chartDetails.data]"></nvd3>
</div>
```

I am getting error as:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasChildNodes' of null
```

The error is coming because chartElement is coming as null. I debugged the code and found that nvd3 is not getting rendered. **Please help me fix this.**

Note: I tried using setTimeOut in spec.ts and test cases were passing, but I don't want to use setTimeout() in spec file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most probably not related to the `setTimeout` method since it is never invoked given the setup of your unit test.

`setTimeout` is invoked only in case `chartDetails.data` is defined, this is however never the case.

As a first step towards a solution, you could try to initialize the component as follows:

```
it('shall render the chart', fakeAsync(() => {
  component.chartDetails = {
    data: [
      { x: 0, y: 3.160340011 },
      { x: 1, y: 5.16379641 },
      { x: 2, y: 1.16379641 },
      { x: 3, y: -1.16379641 },
      { x: 4, y: 0.379641 },
      { x: 5, y: 0 },
      { x: 6, y: -15.16379641 },
      { x: 7, y: -111.16379641 }
    ]
  };
  fixture.detectChanges();
  ...
}));
```